# Showing pictures on a map in the web version of Google Photos

Tags: google-photos

On my phone, the Google Photos [app can show my pictures as a heatmap](https://www.makeuseof.com/map-view-google-photos-see-images-on-map/) on an overlay of a Google Maps map. I have yet to find something similar on the web version. Is this possible?

I frequently find that I want to find some picture taken on my cabin, which is in the middle of nowhere (with no name to show for it in the pre-listed locations). If I could just zoom in on the map, I would have no trouble filtering it down, but this only seems possible on my phone.

Comment: From the tag usage guidance: "Questions about usage and problems should generally be asked at webapps.stackexchange.com unless they involve integration with PC-based software."